# Dynamic Height change in responsive layout

Tags: responsive-design

I have a block element DIV with a fixed width and height. I used a background image for this DIV. We can change the width dynamically using percentages (%).

Is it possible to get the proportional height for that width? If so, how can we accomplish this?

Here's an example:

100px width #div has height:20px;
So, 50px width #div has height:10px;

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use height: 0 with a percentage padding-top.

Check out http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos